# Copying a file character by character in Java

Tags: java, file, filereader, filewriter

I'm working on an exercise where I must copy a file character by character in Java. I am working with the following file:

```
Hamlet.txt
To be, or not to be: that is the question.
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,
And by opposing end them ?
```

I create second file, called `copy.txt` which will contain a character by character copy of `Hamlet.txt` The problem is that after I run my code, `copy.txt` remains empty.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Combinations {
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Hamlet.txt"));
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("copy.txt")));
        copyFileCharByChar(rd, wr);
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.toString());
    }
}

private void copyFileCharByChar(BufferedReader rd, PrintWriter wr) {
    try {
        while(true) {
            int ch = rd.read();
            if(ch == - 1) break;
            wr.print(ch);
        }
      } catch(IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.toString());
    }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Combinations().run();
}
}
```

So I write a method `copyFileCharByChar` that takes in a `BufferedReader` object `rd` and a `FileWriter` object `wr`. `rd` reads each individual character and the `wr` writes that corresponding character. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: btw, why `new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter`? `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter` or `new FileWriter` is sufficient.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Each level increases the efficiency of the writer object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast print in this case:

```
wr.print((char)ch);
```

or use the write method:

```
wr.write(ch);
```

You also need to close your PrintWriter:

```
wr.close();
```

Comment: I don't  agree with the first statement. It works without casting to `char` (because the OP writes the result of `rd.read()` which is already an ascii code).

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Actually, without the case it just prints numbers since ch is an int. But the write method requires no cast, only if i'm calling print.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm I regret, I tested without the cast and it works like a charm. The API takes and int which is the ASCII code of the character. Therefore, in order to write `1`, you would call `wr.print(0x31)`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle `wr.print(int)` print integers _as text_, no?  Here is what the [API says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(int)): "Prints an integer. The string produced by String.valueOf(int) is translated into bytes..."

Comment: @whiskeyspider It seems that we are not calling the same method. On my jvm (8), the called method (with or without cast) is the same: `PrintWriter#write(int c)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write-int-

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm Sorry, my bad, I was calling `write` instead of `print`.